# Lookup from comma separated values in columns and write maximum value - excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

[image]

The input values are in column 1,2 & 3 and the output values are in column 4.

I want to Vlookup values in Column 3 (comma separated values of Pipe Numbers- column1) read these values and find the values from column 2 and write the maximum values for Maximum time of concentration.

For example, Pipe 4,

U/s connected pipes are 1,2,3 & 4 (column 3)
Design time - column 4 will be maximum of Tc (column 2) of 1,2,3,4

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: I am doing on excel one drive and I have 2007 version installed.

Comment: Excel 2007? Also how do you get for the first three rows as 5,6,8 since look up value is 0

Comment: Its an output I want if value in column  is zero then it will read on same raw column 2

Comment: Ah okay, so what version of Excel you are using please clarify that. Excel 2007 is no more supported, its outdated, how can you use? Can you confirm again ? are you really using Excel 2007

Comment: Are you using Excel on Web?

Comment: I can access 2013 version if 2007 not supported.

Comment: Try using this : `=IFERROR(MAX(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(C2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"),$A$2:$B$7,2,0)),B2)` you need to press CTRL SHIFT ENTER

Comment: I can purchase office 365 if it can resolve my ansewers.

Comment: Thank  you Mukesh for the formula Much appreciated ! But I think at some point it is not working for Pipe No 6 - Ansewer is coming 7 , it should be 11 ( max of 7,11,8)

Comment: That works for me, can you refer the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try these formulas below, provided **Excel** dependent

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2` --> **Formula applicable in Excel 365 For Windows/MAC/Web**

```
=MAX(XLOOKUP(0+TEXTSPLIT(C2,,",",1),$A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7,B2))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=MAX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(C2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"),$A$2:$B$7,2,0),B2))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=MAX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C2,",",REPT(" ",100)),ROW($1:$10)*100-99,100))*1,""),$A$2:$B$7,2,0),B2))
```

---

**Note:** Depending on one's Excel version this may needs to be keyed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.